# CRA: Extract particularly big modules into separate chunks?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, code-splitting

Using latest CRA. All `node_modules` are bundled into a separate chunk, which is nice. But that chunk is still over several megabytes in size. At the same time I do not see any option to override or customize chunking logic in CRA. Basically I would like to extract particularly big modules from that `node_modules` chunk and have them loaded as separate chunks entirely. Is it possible without ejecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with [React.Lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) it will separate specific components from the main chunk.

```
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));
```

See [Code-Splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#code-splitting).

If you don't want to eject see [`react-app-rewired`](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) or use other services than CRA like [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/).

Comment: main chunk not that big, so not worried about it at the moment, I want to split vendor chunk (the one that holds all the node_modules)

Comment: You must eject or use react-app-rewired.

Answer (score 3):

Like Dennis mentioned, [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) is one good way. 
But if you want to fully control the modules that comes from node_modules or actually from anywhere in your project - please have a look at [webpack splitchunks](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#optimizationsplitchunks)

This will give you the ability decide which module goes to which chunk.
A quick example:

```
optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                monaco_editor: {
                    test: /monceo-editor[\\/]/,
                    name: 'monaco_editor',
                    maxSize: MaxChunkSize,
                    minSize: MinChunkSize
                },
            }
        }
    }
```

For example here I'm saying take all the modules(files) under monaco-editor directory and put them in one bucket - this bucket will be later separate to multiple chunks each with min size of MinChunkSize and max size of MaxChunkSize.

**The vendor chunk is the automatic cache group that is added by webpack. - It pulls all modules from node_modules that are not loaded dynamically and put them in one chunk.**

You can disable this behavior by setting:

```
cacheGroups: {
    defaultVendors: null
}
```

You can define your own simple/complex node_modules distribution. You can define certain packages to always go to certain chunks. This way the chunk cache won't change unless you upgrade one of the packages version - this is good practice for performance since this cache will be most likely serve from cache.

Here is a more complex example which is good for performance:

```
optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                myVendor: {
                    test: /node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name(module) {
                        const matched = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/);
                        const packageName = matched && matched.length > 2 ? matched[1] : undefined;

                        return packageName;
                    },
                    maxSize: MaxChunkSize,
                    minSize: MinChunkSize
                },
            }
        }
    }
```

In this example, each package will be push to it's own bucket. Now the bucket will merge or split by the min/max size.

Comment: Chunk splitting comes pre-configured with CRA, the problem is that it doesn't let you to customize itself.